# I want to FTP (put) files into a directory that I find with the "find" command in Bash

Tags: bash, ftp, find, put

```
ftp -inv $HOST >> $TMPLOGFILE 2>&1 << ENDFTP
user $USER $PASS
binary
cd gpeh
lcd gpeh
put nameoffile *this is where I want the results of the "find" to go*
bye
ENDFTP
```

The above is the code that I am using to ftp, and below, is an example find script.

```
find ./gpeh
```

So basically what I want to do, is take all of the files that are in the host machines "gpeh" folder, and then put them in the remote machines "gpeh" folder.   Sometimes the number of files will be 1 (well, in most cases it should be 1, the only time it won't be is if the ftp the previous hour failed, so the original file is still there along with the new one that was added this hour), and sometimes it will be more.

If I just wanted to say delete the files that I find in the gpeh folder using the "find" command, I could just use

```
find ./gpeh | xargs delete "and whatever conditions here"
```

But I can't do this within the FTP (or maybe I can), so I'm really not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance for the he

Comment: Why use `ftp`?  This is trivial with `scp`: `find gpeh -type f -exec scp {} user@remote:/path \;`

Comment: If scp is not an option, I would suggest using the lftp client, which provides the mput/mget/mirror commands, which can be used to up/download multiple files or even directory hierarchies.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
#!/bin/bash
PUT_FILES=$(find . -name "*" -printf "put %p\n")

ftp -inv $HOST >> $TMPLOGFILE 2>&1 << ENDFTP
user $USER $PASS
binary
cd gpeh
lcd gpeh
$PUT_FILES
bye
ENDFTP
```

**Explanation**

- `find . -name "*" -printf "put %p\n"` In current directory `.` any name files `"*"`, print format the output as `"put %p\n"`
- `PUT_FILES=$(...)` Capture the output to variable.
- `$PUT_FILES` Will be expanded and executed via ftp.